# Is there a way to Finalize() or Dispose() a Module in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Is there a way to Finalize() or Dispose() a Module in VB.NET? Have a situation similar to the following and need to Dispose() itsUnManagedObject.

```
Public Module ABC
    Private itsUnManagedObject as <Something>
End Module
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the short answer is 'no'.  You can't dispose a module.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7825002w(v=vs.80).aspx

You can call .Dispose() on the 'itsUnmanagedObject'.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think modules are meant to be instantiated and I know modules can't Implement iDisposable.